# Dovecot IMAP server failure

Tags: dovecot, imap

I'm trying to configure an email server. I'm using squirrelmail, dovecot and postfix. When I try to login on squirrelmail site it gicves me

```
ERROR: Connection dropped by IMAP server.
```

The /var/log/mail.err file says

```
dovecot: imap(userName): Error: Mail access for userrs with UID 110 not permitted
(see first_valid_uid in config file, uid from userdb lookup).
```

I assume that this is pretty easy to fix, but I'm new to servers and I'm unable to do it.

Comment: Have you followed the `see first_valid_uid in config file` already?

Comment: You need to check who the owner of the mailboxes is. By default, dovecot set first_valid_uid to 500, you need to modify this value if UID is lower than 500.

Comment: How can I modify this value?